# Springboot : How to remove an annotation on a subclass property?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using Springboot with MongoDB, and I have a class like this :

```
class Mcq {
   @DBRef public List<Question> questions;
}

class McqInstance extends Mcq {
   // Here I want a List<QuestionAnswers> questions instead, without DBRef
}
```

How can I do such a thing, is that possible ? Or should I redeclare McqInstance without extending Mcq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to UserF40's answer, I found a simple solution without have redundant code : use an abstract class :

```
abstract class AbstractMcq {
   // common properties and functions
}

class Mcq extends AbstractMcq {
    @DBRef public List<Question> questions;
}

class McqInstance extends AbstractMcq {
  public List<QuestionAnswers> questions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Redeclare without extending. Off that brief snippet , for modelling Multiple Choice Questions, extends does not seem right.

Ask yourself why do the users need to extend from a class with questions?

Comment: I need to extend the main class because in McqInstance, questions are randomized and answers's order too, + maybe all questions are not used in an instance of Mcq [...]
I didn't wanted to redeclare my class because it will make my code redundant, but I use your advice and found an alternative :
I'll declare a AbstractMcq object without the question list, and I'll extend it in Mcq class and McqInstance class